# Google search redirect to HongKong google.com.hk on iPhone

Tags: iphone, redirect, safari, google-search

I'm in Vietnam and I use google.com on Safari to search. After entering keyword, google redirect to site (as following image):

[image]

I suppose I got some harm infection. How can I cure it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using Google.

Answer (score 1):

I did find the answer, the reason is somehow my phone set region in China. I change the region in Setting/ General/ Language & region and then change the region to my current country and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think I might have had a virus that has changed my region to China Mainland. Switched to US and everything is back to normal now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).